# how to design the Spark application so that Shuffle data will be automatically cleaned up after some iterations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, shuffle

In the Spark core "example" directory (I am using Spark 1.2.0), there is an example called "SparkPageRank.scala",

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("PageRank")
val iters = if (args.length > 0) args(1).toInt else 10
val ctx = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val lines = ctx.textFile(args(0), 1)
val links = lines.map{ s =>
  val parts = s.split("\\s+")
  (parts(0), parts(1))
}.distinct().groupByKey().cache()
var ranks = links.mapValues(v => 1.0)

for (i <- 1 to iters) {
  val contribs = links.join(ranks).values.flatMap{ case (urls, rank) =>
    val size = urls.size
    urls.map(url => (url, rank / size))
  }
  ranks = contribs.reduceByKey(_ + _).mapValues(0.15 + 0.85 * _)
}

val output = ranks.collect()

ctx.stop()
```

}

I realize that in this example, the lineage will keep extending after each iteration. As a result, when I monitored the directory that holds the shuffle data, the shuffle data storage keeps increasing after each iteration.

How should I structure the application code, so that the ContextCleaner's doCleanupShuffle will be activated after certain interval (say, several iterations), so that I can prevent the ever-increasing of the shuffle data storage for computation that takes many iterations?

Jun

Comment: Well if you partition your data you won't have to shuffle every time

Comment: @JunLi Are you still facing this problem? Are you using yarn/mesos external shuffle service?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the clean-up of the shuffle files happens when the objects used for the shuffle are GCed. Since your snippet is a simple example of Page rank, I assume you are running it on a very small dataset, therefore your memory never exceeds the size of the heap and the objects are never GCed. Try with a bigger file or trigger the GC manually (although it is usually not recommended).

More information on : https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/5074/files

By the way in your example, it would be more efficient to partition the data instead of shuffling it every time.

Comment: Following the link https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/5074/files, and the test suite ContextCleanerSuite.scala provided in the Spark distribution,  what is GCed is the Shuffle-Dependency objects. Once the Shuffle-Dependency objects are GC-ed, the cleaner on weak-reference objects will be triggered.  Could you explain the life cycle of a Shuffle-Dependency?

Comment: I don't know more than you about this topic, I just came accross some threads while trying to answer you